# Happo.io Integration with playwright, mobile is a bit different than desktop how do I configure

Tags: javascript, playwright

I have two different environments to run happo tests with playwright using the happo playwright integration.  The mobile environment is different from the desktop and so I need to have 2 test files one for mobile and one for desktop.  The problem is defining the happo.js and playwright.config.js so that i use the correct browser and configurations based on mobile or desktop.  Is this possible?